# Tidy up a dataframe where each column contains more than one variable

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have 4 sensors, `T1, T2, T3, T4`, acquiring data at regular intervals in time. Each sensor is located at a different radial and angular position. These data are stored like this:

```
test_data <- data.frame(T1=c(0,0,rnorm(3),NA,rnorm(6)), T2=c(1,0,NA,NA,rnorm(8)), T3=c(0,2*pi,rnorm(9),NA), T4=c(1,2*pi,rnorm(1),NA,rnorm(8)))
```

i.e., the first two rows of column containing the observations for sensor *i* contain respectively the radius and the angular position of the sensor. The following rows store the measures acquired from the sensor. Some measurements may be missing,

I would like to have a data frame in *tidy* format, thus each column should contain only 1 variable. This means that radius and angle must get their own columns. Consequently, the sensor measurements cannot be stored anymore in parallel columns, but must be stored serially. The second step is easy:

```
library(tidyr)
test_data <- test_data %>% gather(Sensor, Temperature)
```

However, I'm not sure which is the most idiomatic way to perform the first step. Of course I could use a `for` loop, but I was wondering if there could be a  more idiomatic way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
angle <- test_data %>%
  slice(1:2) %>%
  t %>%
  data.frame %>%
  setNames(., c("Radial", "Angular")) %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("Sensor")

test_data %>%
  slice(3:nrow(.)) %>%
  gather(Sensor, Temperature) %>%
  left_join(angle)
```

---

Or as per mentioned in the comments, the more idiomatic:

```
test_data %>% 
  gather(Sensor, Temperature) %>%
  group_by(Sensor) %>% 
  mutate(r = first(Temperature), theta = nth(Temperature,2)) %>% 
  slice(3:n())
```

Comment: Hey, nice! But I think creating an additional data frame and then joining is unnecessary. What about `test_data_tidy <- test_data %>% group_by(Sensor) %>% mutate(r = Temperature[1], theta = Temperature[2]) %>% slice(3:nrow(.))`? And thanks for teaching me `slice`, I didn't know about that.

Comment: @DeltaIV Yup that's also a valid approach. Maybe using `.. r = first(Temperature), theta = nth(Temperature, 2)` is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but I don't believe you need to `slice` and `join`. Simply transpose your data and add a column for the `Sensor` using the column names of the original data:

```
test_data <- data.frame(t(test_data), Sensor=colnames(test_data))
```

Then, you can `gather`. Here, I added column names for each measurement for convenience:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test_data %>% setNames(c("Radial", "Azimuth", paste0("M",1:(ncol(test_data)-3)), "Sensor")) %>% 
              gather("Measurement", "Temperature", M1:M10)
```

For the following input generated with `set.seed(123)`:

```
test_data <- structure(list(T1 = c(0, 0, -0.560475646552213, -0.23017748948328, 
1.55870831414912, NA, 0.070508391424576, 0.129287735160946, 1.71506498688328, 
0.460916205989202, -1.26506123460653, -0.686852851893526), T2 = c(1, 
0, NA, NA, -0.445661970099958, 1.22408179743946, 0.359813827057364, 
0.400771450594052, 0.11068271594512, -0.555841134754075, 1.78691313680308,  
0.497850478229239), T3 = c(0, 6.28318530717959, -1.96661715662964, 
0.701355901563686, -0.472791407727934, -1.06782370598685, -0.217974914658295, 
-1.02600444830724, -0.72889122929114, -0.625039267849257, -1.68669331074241, 
NA), T4 = c(1, 6.28318530717959, 0.837787044494525, NA, 0.153373117836515, 
-1.13813693701195, 1.25381492106993, 0.426464221476814, -0.295071482992271, 
0.895125661045022, 0.878133487533042, 0.821581081637487)), .Names = c("T1", 
"T2", "T3", "T4"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
##            T1         T2         T3         T4
##1   0.00000000  1.0000000  0.0000000  1.0000000
##2   0.00000000  0.0000000  6.2831853  6.2831853
##3  -0.56047565         NA -1.9666172  0.8377870
##4  -0.23017749         NA  0.7013559         NA
##5   1.55870831 -0.4456620 -0.4727914  0.1533731
##6           NA  1.2240818 -1.0678237 -1.1381369
##7   0.07050839  0.3598138 -0.2179749  1.2538149
##8   0.12928774  0.4007715 -1.0260044  0.4264642
##9   1.71506499  0.1106827 -0.7288912 -0.2950715
##10  0.46091621 -0.5558411 -0.6250393  0.8951257
##11 -1.26506123  1.7869131 -1.6866933  0.8781335
##12 -0.68685285  0.4978505         NA  0.8215811
```

You get:

```
##   Radial  Azimuth Sensor Measurement Temperature
##1       0 0.000000     T1          M1 -0.56047565
##2       1 0.000000     T2          M1          NA
##3       0 6.283185     T3          M1 -1.96661716
##4       1 6.283185     T4          M1  0.83778704
##5       0 0.000000     T1          M2 -0.23017749
##6       1 0.000000     T2          M2          NA
##7       0 6.283185     T3          M2  0.70135590
##8       1 6.283185     T4          M2          NA
##9       0 0.000000     T1          M3  1.55870831
##10      1 0.000000     T2          M3 -0.44566197
##11      0 6.283185     T3          M3 -0.47279141
##12      1 6.283185     T4          M3  0.15337312
##13      0 0.000000     T1          M4          NA
##14      1 0.000000     T2          M4  1.22408180
##15      0 6.283185     T3          M4 -1.06782371
##16      1 6.283185     T4          M4 -1.13813694
##17      0 0.000000     T1          M5  0.07050839
##18      1 0.000000     T2          M5  0.35981383
##19      0 6.283185     T3          M5 -0.21797491
##20      1 6.283185     T4          M5  1.25381492
##21      0 0.000000     T1          M6  0.12928774
##22      1 0.000000     T2          M6  0.40077145
##23      0 6.283185     T3          M6 -1.02600445
##24      1 6.283185     T4          M6  0.42646422
##25      0 0.000000     T1          M7  1.71506499
##26      1 0.000000     T2          M7  0.11068272
##27      0 6.283185     T3          M7 -0.72889123
##28      1 6.283185     T4          M7 -0.29507148
##29      0 0.000000     T1          M8  0.46091621
##30      1 0.000000     T2          M8 -0.55584113
##31      0 6.283185     T3          M8 -0.62503927
##32      1 6.283185     T4          M8  0.89512566
##33      0 0.000000     T1          M9 -1.26506123
##34      1 0.000000     T2          M9  1.78691314
##35      0 6.283185     T3          M9 -1.68669331
##36      1 6.283185     T4          M9  0.87813349
##37      0 0.000000     T1         M10 -0.68685285
##38      1 0.000000     T2         M10  0.49785048
##39      0 6.283185     T3         M10          NA
##40      1 6.283185     T4         M10  0.82158108
```